# Navigate from One lwc to another and then back to that component on particular div

Tags: lightning-web-components

Parent Component

```
<div if:true={firstdiv}>
 <lightning-input value={value} onchange={handleValue}>
 </lightning-button>
</div>

<div if:true={Seconddiv}>
 <lightning-button variant="neutral" label="Back" onclick= 
  {gotochildcomponent}>
 </lightning-button>
 <lightning-button variant="neutral" label="save" onclick= 
  {saveadata}>
 </lightning-button>
</div>

<div if:true={childflag}>
    <c-add-accesory location-id-to-get={locationidtopass}></c-add-accesory>
</div>
```

Child Component

```
<template>
   <div class="slds-scope">
   <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
   <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-medium-size_12-of-12">
      <div class="AccessoryData">
         <p>Accessory Category</p>
         <template for:each={AccessoryCategoryData} for:item="item">
            <lightning-button class={item.color}  variant={item.variant} value={item.value} key={item.Index} label={item.label}
               data-value={item.FormatId} onclick={AccessoryCategoryDataFn}>
            </lightning-button>
         </template>
         <hr>
         <lightning-button variant="neutral" label="Back" onclick={backtoSecondivofParentComponent}></lightning-button>
      </div>
   </div>
</template>
```

I have 2 div in my parent component 2nd div shows after 1st div hide so on the second div there is a button which takes me to child component and on child component there is a button with onclick "BacktoCongratsScreen".

So I want to go back to the second div in the Parent component.

Answer (score 1):

How do you navigate between components? If you are not using `lightning/navigation`, you can use a function property on the div to toggle the components.

To pass the toggle property from parent to child, you can use as if you are passing attributes in aura, but if it's child to parent you can use an event that will fire from the child component's button event.

Comment: How do i fire event on child component to go back to parent component

Answer (score 0):

Once you go to Child component, again write a `<div>` inside `<template if:true={condition}>` which calls the Parent component and pass some parameters as well if needed.

Ex -

Below your child component code, but inside root  tag.

Both in Parent & Child component, create `@track firstdiv`. In child set that variable to false on click of back button & set is to return call of parent callback as shown below.

```
<template if:true={condition}>
   <div>
      <c-parent-component firstdiv={firstdiv}></c-parent-component>
   </div>
</template>
```

Just set proper boolean values in Child component's JS & you can achieve it.

Comment: Yeah i will go to parent component by this but there are two div in parent component and i want to go to second div as i told one div is hidden and second one shown

Comment: @Areeb Then set another boolean for first div using template condition & handle it while returning back from child component to parent component.

Comment: may you please elobrate how i can do this??? please

Comment: i modified my question please check

Comment: @Areeb To go back to second div, first div div should be hidden right? So create a ```@track firstdiv ``` in child component. Set it false on click of back button in child component & also set and send it back to parent component.  I will change my answer a little to give you example... Check it

Comment: yeah okay send your answer

Comment: Compilation Failure                                                             
                                                                      /c/wesLwc/wesLWC.js:0,0 : LWC1010: Failed to resolve entry for module "wesLWC".

Comment: this error is coming while deploying

Comment: @Areeb Search it on net. But i have used this method in my case too.....Almost had similar requirement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101378/discussion-between-areeb-and-mohit-kulkarni).

Comment: @Areeb check chat room